# Counter Strike Source private server not found in Lan list

Tags: counter-strike-source

I'm not able to find private servers created by my friend on same network/Lan. I have seen many videos on this fix but i didn't got any solution about my problem.

these are the video examples which i have tried

Comment: you should state which solutions you tried and how you try to connect to that server

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeUfILomqfQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OY8uhync1bk
these are the video examples which i have tried

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I once had the same problem as yours. 
Go to control panel then open **network and sharing centre**. From there, click on **change adapter settings** on the left side of your screen. Then right-click on **WiFi adapter** and click on properties. Find **Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)** and open its properties. A new window will open, there click on **advanced** and then uncheck **automatic matric**. After that, write **1** in the text field that just ungreyed below. Then save and close every window. That should work for you.

You can also get some help from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OY8uhync1bk)